# Do drop commands on #temp tables not persist until commit if wrapped in a transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I concatenated a bunch of SQL scripts together that use the same temp table name #Temp. There are no extra `CREATE TABLE #Temp` commands and every `SELECT INTO #Temp` has a corresponding `DROP TABLE #Temp`.

It's formatted like this:

```
SELECT myfield1, myfield2 INTO #Temp FROM MyTable

--Do stuff with #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp

SELECT myfield3, myfield4 INTO #Temp FROM MyTable2

--Do stuff with #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Everything is wrapped in a single `TRY` and `TRANSACTION`. So the first two lines of the entire script are:

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

I keep getting this error: `There is already an object named '#Temp' in the database.`

Is this because even though I'm issuing the DROP command it's not occurring until the transaction commits causing the error?

Is my only option to create #Temp1, #Temp2, etc?

Comment: On the same batch, yes, you will have to name them differently. And I'd also suggest to always use meaningful names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a compile time error.  When the code is compiled, SQL Server is seeing two declarations for `#temp`

The simplest solution is to use different names for the temporary tables.

Answer (score 2):

What you're getting is a compiler error, it's nothing to do with transactions. If I run the following:

```
SELECT myfield1, myfield2 INTO #Temp FROM MyTable

PRINT N'Created the table'
--Do stuff with #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp

PRINT N'Dropped the table'

SELECT myfield3, myfield4 INTO #Temp FROM MyTable2

PRINT N'Created the table again'
--Do stuff with #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp

PRINT N'Dropped the table again'
```

Even though (on my instance), `MyTable` doesn't exist I still get the error:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 10 
>   There is already an object named '#Temp' in the database.

That's because, in the same batch, you are trying to create the same table twice. I know, for a fact, that `#temp` was never created (as it couldn't be due to `MyTable` not existing) Plus the `PRINT` statements weren't executed, showing that nothing was even attempted.

Separate the statements into 2 batches and it'll work fine.

```
SELECT myfield1, myfield2 INTO #Temp FROM MyTable

PRINT N'Created the table'
--Do stuff with #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp

PRINT N'Dropped the table'
GO

SELECT myfield3, myfield4 INTO #Temp FROM MyTable2

PRINT N'Created the table again'
--Do stuff with #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp

PRINT N'Dropped the table again'
```

Comment: I added the `GO` statements but now I get `Incorrect syntax near #Temp` right after the first `DROP TABLE #Temp`. Also, do `GO` statements take variables out of scope? I have some vars like `@fpID INT` declared at the top of the script that it now complains `Must declare the scalar variable "@fpID.`

Comment: Considering you have `--Do stuff with #Temp` I suspect the error is there (you'll need to debug that, we can't do that for you). And yes, variables only persist for the batch they are declared in. if you can't separate the batches you will have to use different names for your objects. You cannot create a same named object twice in the same batch, even if the logic would dictate that the object is dropped before it is created again.

Comment: Doesn't look like the error was coming from `--Do stuff with #Temp`. I think SQL Server was just lonely, kept throwing the error message `EXPECTING CONVERSATION`.